# How can I use google recaptcha in my custom page?

Tags: joomla-3.4, cms, custom-module

1) Get recaptcha keys from http://www.google.com/recaptcha

2) Set these keys to recaptcha plugin and activate it if it's not.

3) Put below code where you want to show recaptcha

php code:

```
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('captcha');
$dispatcher = JDispatcher::getInstance();
$dispatcher->trigger('onInit','dynamic_recaptcha_1');
```

html code inside form tag

```
<div id="dynamic_recaptcha_1"></div>
```

I putted this code in my htmp page:

```
$post = JFactory::getApplication()->input->post;
$dispatcher = JEventDispatcher::getInstance();
$res=$dispatcher->trigger('onCheckAnswer',$post['recaptcha_response_field']);
if(!$res[0]){
    die('Invalid Captcha');
}
```

I placed the above code but after submitting the form I receive a blank page. Can you explain why?

Comment: A blank page is a PHP error page with disabled error reporting. Enable it for development.

Answer (score 4):

> First read carefully in which files the [SO
> answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12860744/2780063) that you quoted
> tells you to put the code.

Also, the code you attached is no longer working in Joomla 3.5. This is due to a change in the reCaptcha plugin. You have to use it like so:

```
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('captcha');
$dispatcher = JEventDispatcher::getInstance();
$dispatcher->trigger('onInit','my_captcha_div');
```

And instead of creating a container like this:

```
<div id="my_captcha_div"></div>
```

create one like the one below:

```
<div id="my_captcha_div" 
    class="g-recaptcha" 
    data-sitekey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
    data-theme="xxxx" 
    data-size="xxxx"></div>
```

Check **[here](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/9544)** also for more information.

For Joomla 3.5 and above use the response from Олег Косарев.

see https://www.1joomla.org/2016/11/display-recaptcha-in-your-custom.html

Answer (score 1):

Joomla 3.x
Correct

```
    $joomla_captcha = JFactory::getConfig()->get('captcha');
if ( $joomla_captcha != '0') {
    JPluginHelper::importPlugin('captcha');
    $dispatcher = JDispatcher::getInstance();
    // This will put the code to load reCAPTCHA's JavaScript file into your <head>
    $dispatcher->trigger('onInit', 'dynamic_recaptcha_1');
    // This will return the array of HTML code.
    $recaptcha = $dispatcher->trigger('onDisplay', array(null, 'dynamic_recaptcha_1', 'class="required"'));
}
```

and

```
if (isset($recaptcha[0]) and $joomla_captcha != "0") {
        echo $recaptcha[0];
}
```

Or replace the three lines above with a shorthand line because `$recaptcha` is not defined if `$joomla_captcha` is `0`.

```
echo (isset($recaptcha[0])) ? $recaptcha[0] : '';
```