# My Captcha stopped working after upgrading to Joomla 3.5

Tags: upgrade, captcha

After upgrading to Joomla 3.5, **my site / extension / custom form captcha stopped working**. It does not show up, and no errors are generated anywhere.

What happened?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Answer for Joomla! users

Well, that is not a very simple one to answer, and others have already tried to explain.
Namely:

[GitHub Issue #9544](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/9544)
[Similar post in Joomla.StackExchange.com](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/15856/how-can-i-use-google-recaptcha-in-my-custom-page)
[Joomla Forum Related Post](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=710&t=874688&sid=25d08b72c4123ab7552a40826e44cd2b&start=30)

What actually happened is that some details of the default captcha included in Joomla changed, and custom form developers **that do not use a certain method to include it in their forms**, need to update their code.

First, **make sure that you are using the latest version of the extension that stopped working**.

If you are 100% sure about that, you would need to contact the custom form developer and let them know of the issue. Including a link to this page may help them.

If you consider yourself to be confident enough with PHP, you can try to dive into the custom form code, and follow the instructions given for developers, below, until an update is issued by the custom form developer.

### Answer for Developers

The ReCaptcha plugin code changed. Specifically, the function `onInit` was changed in file `plugins/captcha/recaptcha/recaptcha.php`. This problem will most certainly occur to your form, if you followed the instructions from [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840015/how-to-use-joomla-recaptcha-plugin-to-my-custom-module#answer-12860744).
Many developers followed this *obviously not so good* idea, instead of using the `JFormField`s, including Virtuemart, HikaShop, and myself.

Surprisingly enough, the `$id` option included in this function, is no longer used. Instead, the file `media/plg_captcha_recaptcha/js/recaptcha.min.js` was introduced, to provide a callback function for the Google ReCaptcha script:
`https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=JoomlaInitReCaptcha2&render=explicit`

For some *hopefully good* reason, the Joomla team hardcoded the expected field class in the recaptcha.js file to be `g-recaptcha` and stopped using the field `id` overall. So, as also indicated in the links provided, any field without this `class`, and a `data-sitekey` attribute with the ReCaptcha Public Key as its value, won't work.

Thankfully, the solution is very simple. Use the `JCaptcha` class instead.

```
$captcha_plugin = JFactory::getConfig()->get('captcha');
if ($captcha_plugin != '0') {
  $captcha = JCaptcha::getInstance($captcha_plugin);
  $field_id = 'your_old_and_useless_id';
  print $captcha->display($field_id, $field_id, 'g-recaptcha');
}
```

And, of course, a one-liner version. Yay!!

```
print (JFactory::getConfig()->get('captcha') != '0') ? JCaptcha::getInstance(JFactory::getConfig()->get('captcha'))->display('old_field_id', 'old_field_id', 'g-recaptcha') : '';
```

Comment: Might you have a look at this: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/23614/12352 ?

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks! I did have a look and left an answer there, too.