# My site's form or captcha stopped working after upgrading to Joomla 3.9.15

Tags: joomla-3.9, captcha, joomla-3.9.15

After upgrading to Joomla 3.9.15, **my site / extension / custom form captcha stopped working**. I get "Please complete the CAPTCHA" or "invalid-input-response" or something like "Invalid Captcha". What happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Answer for Joomla Users

An update of the `Captcha - ReCaptcha` plugin changed the existing functionality and many of the extension developers need to update the way their extensions handled Captcha responses.

So, a first step is **to be 100% sure that you are using the latest version available**!

If you are sure about that, please contact the extension developer and include a link to this page. It may help them.

### Answer for Extension Developers

The `Captcha - ReCaptcha` plugin changed the way they handled the `onCheckAnswer` event. [A similar change happened back in 2016](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/16078/my-captcha-stopped-working-after-upgrading-to-joomla-3-5), where we had to change the way we included captcha plugins.

Your code may look something like this:

```
$captcha = JCaptcha::getInstance(JFactory::getConfig()->get('captcha'));
if (!$captcha->checkAnswer('my-recaptcha-id')) {
  // handle captcha not answered
}
```

Up until now, the `onCheckAnswer` event completely ignored our input. Instead, it loaded the correct response for Google ReCaptcha by calling:

```
$input->get('g-recaptcha-response', '', 'string');
```

[This changed on 25 Dec 2019](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/commit/0e81a7769ac33f8fc2964d03fbbd5f756d85798b#diff-4bc8a06d78752733c9531d61a8f51c42). Now, our input is used to directly validate the captcha response. So, an easy way to bypass this is to do the following:

```
if (!$captcha->checkAnswer(null)) {
  // handle captcha not answered
}
```

If you want your code to be 100% consistent, then assuming you have:

```
print JCaptcha::getInstance(JFactory::getConfig()->get('captcha'))->display('my_field_id', 'my_field_id', 'g-recaptcha');
```

You would write:

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
if (!$captcha->checkAnswer($input->get('my_field_id', null, 'string')) {
  // handle captcha not answered
}
```

**BUT!** You have to remember that the ReCaptcha plugin ignores our Captcha ID input anyway, so the above currently serves as a nice wrapper around `null` anyway.